# Transaction Stickiness

Tags: java, http, transactions, jax-rs

We're using jersey 1.8.3 with embedded jetty 8 server, in Active-Active mode, using a load-balancer.

For one of our use-cases, we need some kind of stickiness - not the standard stickiness where a client sends all the requests to the same node, but only for a specific transaction - which mean a set of requests where the first one creates the transaction in the server, and the last one commits the changes, then the transaction is dead.

We implemented it by sending full URL in the location response header of create transaction request. We builds the Location URL using the UriInfo.getBaseUri() method.

This approach does not work for several reasons, e.g. in some deployments there is no direct access to the servers, but only to the load balancer. Also, and I'm still not sure about it, UriInfo.getBaseUri() returns the LB address rather than the server address.

Is there any standard way to achieve the above? Any other idea?

Thanks!